# Как в 1С определить месторасположение объекта?

Tags: 1с

Для примера есть такая форма документа:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Берём столбец `Инв. №`. С помощью подсказок определил, что он находится в `РегистрСведений.ПервоначальныеСведенияОСБухгалтерскийУчет.Ресурс.ИнвентарныйНомер`.

Как определить, где месторасположение столбца `Инв. №`? (если бы не знал где находится) Какие есть способы?

Comment: Встань на нужном элементе формы и нажми "Ctrl+F12" - команда "Перейти".

Answer (score 1):

У поля есть свойство `ПутьКДанным`:

> [7.7.2.2.2. Связь с обычным реквизитом формы](https://its.1c.ru/db/v8311doc/bookmark/dev/TI000000407)
>
> В простейшем случае элемент формы отображает значение, сохраненное в каком-либо реквизите формы. В зависимости от типа реквизита, система автоматически определяет, какой элемент формы будет использоваться для отображения данных, и какого вида будет этот элемент (если такое возможно).
>
> В этом случае свойство Путь к данным содержит имя реквизита формы, чьи данные будут отображены этим элементом.

Поле `ОСИнвентарныйНомер` ссылается на `Объект.ОС.ИнвентарныйНомер`, где:

- `Объект` — Документ ИнвентаризацияОС
- `ОС` — Табличная часть документа
- `ИнвентарныйНомер` — Реквизит табличной части

Answer (score 0):

Встаем на элемент и щелкаем правой кнопкой - команда Перейти